# SharePoint is not working after setting up the Outlook Web Access

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, error, events

I am working on SharePoint 2010. I am facing problem as SharePoint stopped unexpectedly. I am working on UAT server on client side. So its urgent.

We are facing the problem since we were fixing the issues to access the OWA (Outlook Web Access). Now we can access the OWA.

**We are facing same problem with Administrator account too.**

**The Main Problem:**

1. I cant open the Central Administration site. When I am going to open the CA it throws an error page with "Unexpected error". So I cant access the CA and unable to try solutions that I found on the internet.

Facing same when browsing from IIS.

1. All the other sites are also not working and giving page with error "404 Page not found".

Facing same when browsing from IIS.

**Some Details:**

1. All the sites are running in IIS.
2. All application pools in IIS are running.
3. All the required services are running.

**Error :** Please find the Event log details below.

**1) First error is:**

WebHost failed to process a request.
 Sender Information: System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment+HostingManager/17653682
 Exception: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The service

'/SecurityTokenServiceApplication/securitytoken.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The

exception message is: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.. --->

System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. --->

System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: certificate
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityToken..ctor(X509Certificate2 certificate, String id, Boolean clone,

Boolean disposable)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityToken..ctor(X509Certificate2 certificate)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.SecurityTokenService.X509SigningCredentials..ctor(X509Certificate2 certificate)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPSecurityTokenServiceConfiguration..ctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean&

canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandle& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo

culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustServiceHostFactory.CreateSecurityTokenServiceConfiguration

(String constructorString)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String constructorString,

Uri[] baseAddresses)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPSecurityTokenServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String constructorString,

Uri[] baseAddresses)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.ActivateService(String normalizedVirtualPath)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.EnsureServiceAvailableFast(String relativeVirtualPath)
 Process Name: w3wp
 Process ID: 4784

Event ID : 3
Task Category : WebHost

**2) Second Error is:**

An exception occurred when trying to issue security token: The requested service,

'http://localhost:32843/SecurityTokenServiceApplication/securitytoken.svc/actas' could not be activated. See the

server's diagnostic trace logs for more information..

Event ID : 8306
Task Category : Claims Authentication

**3) Third Error is:**

Alternate access mappings have not been configured.  Users or services are accessing the site `http://server:2222` with

the URL `http://server:1111`.  This may cause incorrect links to be stored or returned to users.  If this is expected,

add the URL `http://server:1111` as an AAM response URL.  For more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=114854"/>

Event ID : 8059
Task Category : Configuration

All the errors are coming back to back. I tried to find the solution on the internet and found some solution but all the solutions are related to UI.

**What I think:**

It looks like it is an authentication problem but unable to find (or resolve) the (exact) problem.

**Questions:**

1. How to resolve the issue so that SharePoint come again in working?
2. Is there any impact of fixing the OWA ? if yes then what?
3. Is it permission issue? if yes then how can it be happen because
   same user and permission were working earlier.
4. Why the same problem is coming with the Administrator too?
5. Why different error on CA site and other error on other sites?

Please help as it is very urgent.

- Khan Abubakar

Comment: Abubakar, can you make sure Application Pools are not stopped and are running?

Comment: Yes, all application pools are running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First question is why is OWA being installed on the same box that is hosting SharePoint, generally you'd run OWA on the Exchange server itself? From what it looks like on the surface the errors you've posted might not actually have anything to do with the problem, unless you are running Claims Based authentication for your web application.

First error related to Claims Based authentication, second error I see frequently on servers that are not configured for claims based auth and can usually be ignored. Last error related to your alternate access mappings, seems the server is getting requests on `http://server:2222` rather than what its configured for `http://server:1111`.

What I'd do is start looking at the ULS logs, go get the msdn log viewer http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ULSViewer and open ULS try hit central admin and see what it spits out. I'm thinking OWA might have screwed with the IIS site for SharePoints Central Admin site. Other questions are, are all your web applications down or just Central Admin? For example your `http://server:1111` or the Mysite web application if you're using that. It might also be that the OWA install process has reconfigured for 'Negotiate' see my post [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/47336/wss-3-0-site-accessible-only-locally-and-when-using-ip-address/47390#47390) if you need to check that. Might also be that OWA install has installed something on the sharepoint server thats been slapped into the SharePoint web application web.config files and now it won't load the site.

Comment: Thanks @pigeon for the answer.
about the sites: all the sites not working. I am facing "Unexpected error" on central admin and "404 page not found" on other sites.
Now I have ran the configuration wizard then I found your post. I am facing problem posted here [link](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/49742/unable-to-rerun-the-configuration-wizard-found-error-on-accessserverwebservicei).  
Please help its urgent.

Comment: looked at the other post, seems like an odd place to have the configuration wizard fail and fairly terminal at that. I'm assumign you're re-running the confiugration wizard as a local admin or the farm service account, it seems like the OWA installation has caused some changes perhaps to some of the framework files that SharePoint rely on. Personally if i was in your position I'd build a new SharePoint server, setup a new farm and then backup & restore the content database to that, unless you happen to have a snapshot or backup of the server prior the OWA install.

Comment: I have completed the config wizard using this [post](http://blogit.create.pt/blogs/antoniovargas/archive/2009/12/01/SharePoint-2010_3A00_-Failed-to-register-SharePoint-Services-on-configuration-wizard.aspx). But the problems that I have asked in this question (3 issues above) are still exist. No Profit and time loss.
Regarding OWA Install : OWA configuring was done to access the mail box and on server it is not working. For the same user from other machine (laptop) we can access the OWA mail box.

Comment: Abubakar, have you investegated the ULS logs yet using the ULS log viewer I linked to above? If you've been able to complete the products and technologies wizard then it seems like SharePoint should be accessible, so its likely something in IIS is set wrong. The event logs aren't giving you the insight you need to solve it.