# Unable to rerun the configuration wizard found error on "AccessServerWebServiceInstance"

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-services

This is similar to the post [My Problem](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/49726/sharepoint-is-not-working-after-setting-up-the-outlook-web-access/49733#49733).
I re-ran the sharePoint Configuration wizard and found error at step 4. searched on the internet but unable to find the solution.

**Problem is:** (Please refer the image below)
Failed to register SharePoint services.
An exception of type System.ArgumentException was thrown.  Additional exception information: An object in the SharePoint administrative framework, "AccessServerWebServiceInstance", depends on other objects which do not exist.  Ensure that all of the objects dependencies are created and retry this operation.
[image]

Please help. Its very urgent.

Thanks in advance.

- Khan Abubakar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this using the steps given [here](http://blogit.create.pt/blogs/antoniovargas/archive/2009/12/01/SharePoint-2010_3A00_-Failed-to-register-SharePoint-Services-on-configuration-wizard.aspx). I did this for all the service Instance (like "AccessServerWebServiceInstance").
Configuration wizard is completed successfully but the problem in my post [My Problem](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/49726/sharepoint-is-not-working-after-setting-up-the-outlook-web-access/49733#49733) is still exist.

Comment: this link is 404 :(